# Creating new filter in django

Tags: django

I would like to use a `range` filter in django. Something like this :

```
<br>
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Revenue streams</th>
        <th>Units</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        {% for num in 2022|range:2027 %}
          <th>{{ num }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
</thead>
```

So I have created a **templatetags** folder in my app and added file **custom-filters.py** that contains :

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def range(start, end):
    return range(start, end + 1)
```

but the page returns :

[image: Example of the use of the range filter]

**Any idea of what is mising?**

Comment: In your template do you have `{% load  custom-filters %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the method name `range` to something else like `range_until`. You also need to load the filter into your template (not sure you did that).

filter:

```
@register.filter
def range_until(start, end):
    return range(start, end + 1)
```

Template:

```
{% load test_filters %}

<br>
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Revenue streams</th>
        <th>Units</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        {% for num in 2022|range_until:2027 %}
          <th>{{ num }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
</thead>
```

I also recommend you to change the filename and not to use hyphens. E.g. `custom_filters.py`

Comment: Spot on, you rock ! Thansk ;)